# How much quran should I recite each day?

Tags: quran-recitation, waswasa

Is it ok for me to read 1 ruku everyday or is that not sufficient?

I used to read quran often, at least 3 ruku a day and tried memorising new surahs and preserving these memorisations.

But ever since I was afflicted with OCD and wiswas I have abandoned the quran and I barely read it. I just feel too lazy and demotivated to read it. My wiswas is to do with najasah and doubts about missing the pillars of acts of worship

I feel like coming back to the quran by reciting at least 1 ruku a day and then gradually increase the recitation of the quran.

Comment: What is 1 ruku? Please clarify/elaborate!

Comment: 1 ruku is around 10 ayahs. But it varies. Sometimes it can be more or less than 10 ayahs. Ruku is represented with the letter ع on top of an ayah. I'm surprised that you don't know what a ruku is.

Comment: Ruku or ع isn't an agreed upon standard. It's rather some local custom.

Comment: @MuhammadAbdulMuhit as many as you can is great. but beside of reading all Quran, you can read Tohid surat 3 times. it's like that you read all the Quran. (Prophet Mohammad)

Answer (score 1):

**In Islam,** it is **permissible to recite/read: Any amount of ayats, rukus, surahs, juz as long as you dont finish the Quran in less than 3 days**, in example:

- an ayat a day
- a ruku a day,
- a surah a day,
- a juz a day,
- 10 juz a day,

**Your question: is 1 reciting/reading ruku a day sufficient?**

This is permissible as you wouldn't be abandoning the Quran.

Comment: “Just as long as you don’t finish the Quran in less than 3 days” —where does this come in to play exactly?

Comment: In Ibn Maajah (1347)

Comment: Please, add the Hadiths to your post to support your answer.

Comment: What happens if you finish it in less than 3 days? Or should I make a separate question about this

Answer (score 1):

Bismillah. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Ashraful Anbiya Sayyidina Muhammad wa 'ala 'Alihi Muhammad.

---

Refer to following hadith from Al-Kafi as an instruction

> (It has been narrated) from Abu Abdullah (asws) having said: ‘The
> Quran is a Covenant of Allah (azwj) to His (azwj) creatures. Thus, it
> is befitting for the Muslim person that he looks into his covenant,
> and that he recites from it, **during every day, fifty Verses**’.
>
> [Source: Al Kafi V 2 – The Book Of Merits of the Quran CH 5 H 1](https://hubeali.com/books/English-Books/AlKafiVol2/AlKafiV2-TheBookOfMeritsOfTheQuran.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You can recite as much as you can easily manage as there is no evidence which obligates recitation of a minimum amount, rather Allah says:

> فاقرءوا ما تيسر من القرآن
>
> So recite what is easy [for you] of the Qur'an.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 73:20](https://quran.com/73/20?translations=20)</sup>

Other than this, the Prophet ﷺ advised some of his companions to finish the Quran in [one month](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5052) or [forty days](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:1395) and the salaf used to recite varying amounts, completing it in a single day, three days, seven days, once in month, once in forty days, once in two months etc.